# How does `az account get-access-token --resource api://<appid>` work behind the scenes to retrieve an access token?

Tags: azure, security, azure-active-directory, microsoft-entra-id, azure-entra-id

Consider the following command that attempts to retrieve an access token:

`az account get-access-token --resource api://<appid>`

This works, if the Azure CLI is a preauthorized client application: `04b07795-8ddb-461a-bbee-02f9e1bf7b46`

But how does this command works behind the scenes? I suppose the Azure CLI application has no permissions (scopes) on my app, so that's not an option. Also, I don't believe it's executing an OAuth 2.0 On-Behalf-Of flow, because what would be the middle-tier API in this case?

Thank you!

Comment: When you run the `az account get-access-token` command, the Azure CLI acts as a client application and uses its own credentials to obtain the access token.

Comment: Thank you, but which credentials is it using to obtain the access token? My credentials? Furthermore, how can it obtain an access token for an arbitrary API? Normally, that would require a scope configured on the client? But, the Azure CLI naturally can't have configured scopes for any resource

Comment: AFAIK it is using your credentials, based on the authentication type (az login or az login with app) it chooses the authentication flow. And as the Azure CLI app is added as client application it will be able to generate the token

Comment: The Azure CLI does have configured scopes for the resource because the scopes are determined by the Azure AD application registration that is associated with the resource and hence it uses your credentials to fetch token

Comment: Can you elaborate? In this case, the resource is my Azure AD application exposing a scope, e.g. `api://<appid>`. I cannot see the Azure CLI's app registration from my tenant (`04b07795-8ddb-461a-bbee-02f9e1bf7b46`), but I doubt it has a scope for my resource in its list of configured permissions? As the Azure CLI is added as a preauthorized client, means the user (me) won't get prompted for consent, which it probably don't support, as it's a CLI.

Comment: No the Azure CLI will not be having scope of your resource in its configured permissions

Comment: The specificed client application is add to the preAuthorizedApplications collection of the app manifest. In effect, the consent is granted for all users of that application. If you controlled the application (the Azure CLI, you could write code to prompt for consent to this custom web API [in OAuth words - this custom resource]. But since you do not control those applications, this preAuthorization helps. And since you are using a developer tenant, you are an tenant administrator and have the permission to pre-consent.

Comment: But how can the Azure CLI request a token for a application is has no configured permission for? Suppose that an application "A" has no scope added to its permission list for application "B". Can "A" still request an access token for "B" then?